# My Google Username is a non-Google email address and I used it to log onto a new Pixel 6 Pro which now won't add my Exchange account with same address

Tags: gmail, google-account, exchange, google-pixel-6

I have a new Pixel 6 Pro and have migrated apps and settings from Pixel 3a via my Google ID. My Google Username is my regular Outlook email address and not a Gmail address. When I now go to add my Microsoft Exchange account, I get an error message in red saying 'You have already added this account' because it sees my Google account as an email account, which it isn't.

The 3a ran Outlook for me with my Exchange email address, contacts (4,000+), and calendar quite happily alongside using the same email address as my Google Username. The 6 Pro won't have it!

Five different Google Help operatives over ten days have failed to provide a solution or answer my question which is: Should I get a Gmail address and change my Google Username to that and if I do so on a PC, will I be able to then add my Exchange account on the phone, and will I lose all my app data and set-up on the 6 Pro? The 3a was traded in and is irretrievable.

Any ideas on here would be very welcome.

Comment: Don't your Google account also has a gmail address? Even if you usually use your Outlook mail address as account name I would assume that your Google account then has two email addresses assigned, the Outlook plus a Gmail address. I would remove the google account from your device and re-add it using that GMail address.

Comment: Thanks Ruben - No, my Google account only has one email address, being my Outlook mail address, so I was stuck.  However, as a last effort before doing a factory reset and logging on again with a new Google account and Gmail address, which would have lost the App data, I simply deleted my Google account from the phone!  The world did not end, all the Apps were still there and the phone let me load my Exchange account with Calendar and 4,000+ contacts!  Extraordinary; who would think that the solution for a Google problem on a Google phone is to delete your Google Account!  Ha ha ha!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you say your device "sees" your Google account as an "email account", which do you mean?

[image: Screenshot]

An Exchange account, Google account, and IMAP email account should all be distinct despite it being possible to use the same username string.  Furthermore, your Microsoft account/Office account, Outlook, Outlook.com, OWA, Work/School permutations, etc, can similarly be distinct despite also possibly having the same overlap (I'm not familiar with the specific distinctions on that end, I just recall it was not at all intuitive).  You *should* have the ability to specifically add the exact account types you require, and manually configure them respectively.

Comment: Thanks Arctiic - yes, what you say should all be correct but the phone simply would not give me the option to add the account in any way or method.  I meant what I said:  My Google Username is an email address, the Pixel software thinks I have added that as an email account and wont let me add another account which uses that email address.  Anyway, I stumbled on a solution by simply deleting my Google account from the phone, anticipating Armageddon, but nothing nasty happened and it then let me add my Outlook-based Exchange account and everything is fine, including all the Apps.  Very weird.

Comment: That in itself it also unusual, because it should theoretically allow you to add multiple users of the same account type, i.e., you can have multiple Google accounts added on one phone.  But in any case, whatever the circumstances were, I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

On a Pixel 7 with Android 13, a detour via “Set up manually” worked around the problem for me.

In detail: When you see the message “You have already added this account” when trying to add an Exchange account, e.g.: (the red rectangle is a redaction)

[image]

… then type in another valid e-mail address instead, e.g.:

[image]

Now you can tap on “Set up manually”, resulting in, e.g.:

[image]

You can now type in your real e-mail address in the “Email” field. Do not bother with the other fields unless you have to; instead tap on “Switch to modern auth”. After waiting for “Getting account info…” you can proceed without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [OP's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247805/my-google-username-is-a-non-google-email-address-and-i-used-it-to-log-onto-a-new#comment332861_247810),

> Anyway, I stumbled on a solution by simply deleting my Google account from the phone, anticipating Armageddon, but nothing nasty happened and it then let me add my Outlook-based Exchange account and everything is fine, including all the Apps. Very weird.